# Custom pattern matching with regular expressions and three lists

Tags: python, regex, list

i'm a newbie and i'm trying to build a custom pattern matcher with three dynamically generated lists with the same length. It's for a tool that stores three personal sensible informations, its not that important. I thought putting them into three lists would be good to do some custom pattern matching.
One list for the names, one for their address and one for their personal code. It's confidential so i won't display any names or personal information, instead i use string,regex and placeholder for this to be easier.
Some simple rules for the custom pattern matcher to understand my code:

1. The strings are not unique, they can be repeated multiple times like string1 in my code, so the matcher should test each pattern with each subsequent string.
   2.The pattern matching are done in all three lists, sequentially at the same time
   3.The pattern matching is done by index, so if a pattern match a string in list1 at index 5,the next pattern cannot be matched with a string at index 3 in any list(list1,list2 or list3) for example, it should match a string at index 6 or higher
   4.The custom pattern matcher should match the strings in the list sequentially, in the order they are given, if the character '#' is not in the pattern list. 
   5.'#' is a placeholder for one or more strings in a list in between indexes of the strings before and after the '#' in the pattern list.

with these three lists and pattern_list as example

```
    list1 = ['string1', 'string2', 'string1', 'string3']
    list2 = ['regex1', 'regex2', 'regex1', 'regex3']
    list3 = ['placeholder1', 'placeholder2', 'placeholder1', 'placeholder3']
    pattern_list=['regex2', '#', 'string3']
    #should print ['string2', 'string1', 'string3'] here in that case regex2=index 1(starting from zero)=list1[1]=string2, '#' matches one or more strings, here it's one string, regex1=index 2=list1[2]=string1
```

If that is understood here's the code:

```
import re

def search_pattern(list1, list2, list3, pattern_list):
  # Create the connections dictionary because list1 is connected to the strings in list2 and list3
  connections = {}
  for i in range(len(list1)):
    connections[list1[i]] = (list2[i], list3[i])

  # Convert the pattern list to a regex pattern
  pattern = '|'.join(pattern_list)

  # Initialize the result list
  result = []

  # Iterate over the lists
  for lst in [list1, list2, list3]:
    # Iterate over the strings in the list
    for i, string in enumerate(lst):
      # Check if the string matches the regex pattern
      match = re.search(pattern, string)
      if match:
        # Append the corresponding string from the connections dictionary to the result list
        result.append(connections[string][0] if match.group() == list2 else string)

  # Return the result list
  return result

list1 = ['string1', 'string2', 'string1', 'string3']
list2 = ['regex1', 'regex2', 'regex1', 'regex3']
list3 = ['placeholder1', 'placeholder2', 'placeholder1', 'placeholder3']

# Define the pattern to search for
pattern_list = ['regex2', '#', 'string3']

# Search for the pattern in all lists
result = search_pattern(list1, list2, list3, pattern_list)

# Print the result list
print(result)
```

The problem is that this code gives me ['string3', 'regex2'] instead of ['string2', 'string1', 'string3']. I'm stucked can anyone help me? Maybe it's not the best way to go about it, maybe i should change my code completly? I don't know i need your help

Comment: I don't understand your example at all. There's no "rule" for what should appear in the output, how the patterns are applied to the lists, or how matching one pattern affects matches on another.

Comment: as far as I understood the problem it's quite complicated and totally beyond the scope of newbie...

Comment: "Sequentially at the same time" needs a bit more explanation.  Do you mean that it should check `list1[0], list2[0], list3[0], list1[1], list2[1], list3[1]` in that order ? Or do you mean, `list1[0], list1[1], list1[2] ... list2[0], list2[1], list2[2]... list3[0], list3[1], list3[2]...  etc`  ??

Comment: Please explain your use of list3? and more about how `#` is supposed to find text.

Comment: # is like the regex '.*', list3 is a list of data corresponding to the personal code,list2=adress,list1=names

Comment: @ScottC I meant list1[0], list2[0], list3[0], list1[1], list2[1], list3[1] in that order

Comment: @kosciej16 so could you tell me what to do?

Comment: To make sure, is it true that the result will always be some sublist of list1?

Comment: @kosciej16 yes it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, the `#` in the pattern list will need to be converted to `.*` to find `any` string as intended.
- You seem to be wanting to find a sequence of patterns, rather than all patterns at the same time. So I increment the `pattern` from the `pattern_list` every time a match is found.
- When a match is found, only the `item` from `list_1` at that index is appended to `result`.

Here is the code:

#### Code:

```
import re

def search_pattern(list1, list2, list3, pattern_list):
    
    # Replace # with .* in the pattern list
    pattern_list = list(map(lambda x: x.replace('#', '.*'), pattern_list))
    
    all_lists = [list1, list2, list3]
        
    num = 0
    result = []
    for i, item in enumerate(list1):
        for l in all_lists:
            match = re.search(pattern_list[num], l[i])
            if match:
                result.append(item)
                num += 1
                break;
   
    return result
            
        
list1 = ['string1', 'string2', 'string1', 'string3']
list2 = ['regex1', 'regex2', 'regex1', 'regex3']
list3 = ['placeholder1', 'placeholder2', 'placeholder1', 'placeholder3']

# Define the pattern to search for
pattern_list = ['regex2', '#', 'string3']

# Search for the pattern in all lists
result = search_pattern(list1, list2, list3, pattern_list)

# Print the result list
print(result)
```

#### Output:

```
['string2', 'string1', 'string3']
```

Comment: I used your code  as a basis and found the correct algorithm, but it's too long to post, so i give credit where's dued. Thank you very much ScottC!

Answer (score 1):

Rather than keeping a `str`

```
  pattern = '|'.join(pattern_list)
```

consider compiling to a regex just once:

```
  pattern = re.compile('|'.join(pattern_list))
```

and the later usage then becomes `pattern.search( ... )`

---

Keeping track of the `i`th element of
several related lists seems to be a minor
hassle in this piece of code.

Consider making their association
more explicit, by turning it into
a list of tuples.

(Your code is a bit generic,
so it's not yet clear what the appropriate
business term for the tuple would be.)

```
from collections import namedtuple

Foo = namedtuple("Foo", "string, regex, placeholder")

data = [
    Foo("string1", "regex1", "placeholder1"),
    Foo("string2", "regex2", "placeholder2"),
    Foo("string1", "regex1", "placeholder1"),
    Foo("string3", "regex3", "placeholder3"),
]

for foo in data:
    match = pattern.search(foo.string)
    if match:
        result.append(foo.placeholder
                      if match.group() == list2  # what?!?
                      else foo.string)
```

I'm afraid I don't understand your comparison to `list2`;
it doesn't seem sensible to ask if a `str` will ever
be identical a `list`. Substitute whatever you intended
in that clause.

Comment: Yes there can be placeholders, a str can be a substitute for one or more string(s) inside the lists

Comment: Possibly the [`in`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typesseq-common) operator was intended: `if match.group() in list2` . BTW, testing membership in a large [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set) goes quicker than doing that for the corresponding list.